# Odd coding pattern when releasing the UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

In a lot of code samples, also on the Apple documentation website, you will see this kind of pattern. The UIAlertView is called with "show" and "release" in sequence.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Panic!"
    message:@"The world is gonna explode!"
    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Who cares?"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Boom!", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
NSLog(@"released!");
```

When you run this code, the "released!" log line will be shown while the UIAlertView box is still on screen. It seems like an odd pattern to me to release this object when it's still seen on screen. What is the idea behind this, isn't this against what is common with memory management? If this "show" call would be blocking, I could see how this pattern would be safely freeing the memory. But since the NSLog method is executed, it continues executing your code.

Comment: As the others noted, you're simply release *your* ownership of the UIAlertView, that doesn't mean no one else has it. The `[alert show]` gives ownership to the system, so there's no point in hanging onto it. You'll see it in many places.

Comment: Adding NSLog(@"alert retain cound %d", [alert retainCount]); showed that the retain count indeed incremented a whole bunch. It incremented from 1 to 6 by that single "show" method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`release` doesn’t mean that the object will be disposed off right away. It just means that your code doesn’t want to access it any more after that point. Other code (like the system frameworks) might and so they retained it.

Answer (score 4):

`[alert show];` retains `UIAlertView`

Comment: The thing is, where is it _written_ that `show` retains the alertview?

Comment: by itself it don't. But it adds view to superview and that retains it.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the code you see that when the UIAlertView is being created it is being allocated too. So the retain count of the alert is 1 after that.
If you read the apple documentation you will see that the [alert show] also increase the retain count of the UIAlertView. So, after that line the retain count will be 2.
The line [alert release] will decrease the retain count to 1 again, because, for this code, isn't important to keep reference to the UIAlertView.
So, after that, the retain count is 1, and the UIAlertView is being showed. When the user press the button to close the alert, the method that closes the alert will decrease the retain count to 0 and the memory will be freed

Comment: Whereabouts in the Apple documentation is it stated that -show takes ownership of the UIAlertView?